# bzm parallel controller - generate parent sample aggregates rather than returning the max

Tags: jmeter

bzm parallel controller's generate parent sample sums up all the response time rather than returning just the maximum time. In my test, I am trying to test a page load. There are bunch of API calls all running parallel. 
My sampler adds up the response time of all the request when I have 'generate parent sample' enabled,  while executing them in parallel.

my parallel controller has 2 http requests a PUT and a GET. There is a constant timer at thread group level set at 5seconds. PUT takes 3000ms to complete and GET takes 1000ms to complete, the generate parent sample show the result as 8000ms. The parent sample adds up the constant timer too. Is there a way to not get constant timer added

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using couple of [Dummy Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide):

[image]

Make sure to install the latest version of the [Parallel Sampling for JMeter plugins](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md) (as of now it's [version 0.9)](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.blazemeter/jmeter-parallel/0.9)

You can use [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) to install the [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) and keep them up-to-date

[image]

Also be aware that there is [`jmeter-plugins` forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) where you can reach out to JMeter Plugins developers and/or maintainers.

Comment: Just found the issue on my tests. I have been using a constant timer. Even if the constant timer is placed at the test plan level its getting added to the parent time.

Comment: I think There is a issue when parallel controller used under a transaction controller.

I have

Transaction Controller (Generate Parent Sample Checked) |----> bzm @ parallel controller (Generate Parent Sample Checked) | ---> Bunch of child samples need to run parallel

The timing of the bzm@parallel controller is way too higher than the timings of the child samplers ( not even matches the total of them)

I use jmeter 5.2.1 , parallel controller 0.11

This was discussed in the below google forum, but no fix.

Detailed in here

Anyone know of a workaround or a fix for it yet ???

Comment: I think [documentation](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#limitations) mentions the following: `Parallel Controller does not support work with Transaction Controller so if used you can get an unexpected results.`  The timing of the parallel controller is the highest child response time (if the number of requests < 6) or sum of the highest response times (if the number of requests is > 6). More information: [How to Use the Parallel Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter)